# Pandas filtering based on minimum data occurrences across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
country     data_fingerprint   organization     
US          111                Tesco         
UK          222                IBM          
US          111                Yahoo           
PY          333                Tesco
US          111                Boeing   
CN          333                TCS  
NE          458                Yahoo
UK          678                Tesco
```

I want those data_fingerprint for where the organisation and country with top 2 counts exists

So if see in **organization top 2 occurrences are for Tesco,Yahoo** and for **country we have US,UK** .

So based on that the output of data_fingerprint should be having

```
data_fingerprint
111
678
```

What i have tried for organization to exist in my complete dataframe is this

```
# First find top 2 occurances of organization
nd = df['organization'].value_counts().groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).head(2)
# Then checking if the organization exist in the complete dataframe and filtering those rows
new = df["organization"].isin(nd)
```

But i am not getting any data here.Once i get data for this I can do it along with country
Can someone please help to get me the output.I have less data so using Pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
df[
    df['organization'].isin(df['organization'].value_counts().head(2).index) &
    df['country'].isin(df['country'].value_counts().head(2).index)
]['data_fingerprint'].unique()
```

```
array([111, 678], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: the requirement is that top 2 occurances of country and organization to be present in all records having data_fingerprint .Looks like if one of them matches also its filtering the data_fingerprint

Comment: how else did 678 returned? the solution is to get the top two organization, and top two countries and the fingerprint for the union of these two are returned. you may like to add some more explanation on the expectation

Comment: what i am seeing is 458 is also returned as Yahoo being in Top 2 organisations has that data_fingerprint..Its doing like OR..I need AND matching both country and Organization

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
# First find top 2 occurances of organization
nd = df['organization'].value_counts().head(2).index
# Then checking if the organization exist in the complete dataframe and filtering those rows
new = df["organization"].isin(nd)
```

Output - Only Tesco and Yahoo left

```
df[new]

    country data_fingerprint    organization
0        US              111           Tesco
2        US              111           Yahoo
3        PY              333           Tesco
6        NE              458           Yahoo
7        UK              678           Tesco
```

You can do the same for `country`

Comment: what is the output you are seeing

Comment: thats the point its not working when i combine the columns.

Answer (score 1):

##### Annotated code

```
# find top 2 most occurring country and organization
i1 = df['country'].value_counts().index[:2]
i2 = df['organization'].value_counts().index[:2]

# Create boolean mask to select the rows having top 2 country and org.
mask = df['country'].isin(i1) & df['organization'].isin(i2)

# filter the rows using the mask and drop dupes in data_fingerprint
df.loc[mask, ['data_fingerprint']].drop_duplicates()
```

##### Result

```
   data_fingerprint
0               111
7               678
```

Comment: The isin i think is picking even if all top 2 occurrences arent present in data_fingerprint.the requirement is that top 2 occurances of country and organization to be present in all records having data_fingerprint .Looks like if one of them matches also its filtering the data_fingerprint